# Adding another argument for @Delete JAX-RS method?

Tags: annotations, jersey, jax-rs

The Server Resource receives the call to the below mentioned remove() correctly for 'delete' operation from client side.

```
@DELETE @Path("{id}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public void remove(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        dao.remove(id);
}
```

Here I get the 'id' param also correctly from the path, to delete the record containing the 'id' from the database.

My question is, suppose if I want to get another parameter from the same 'path', say "Password", to validate the entered password before deleting the record, is there a way to do it?

Please let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it's possible to include multiple paramters in a URI template in the `@Path` annotation, so you could have:

```
@Path("{id}/{password}")
@DELETE @Path("{id}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public void remove(@PathParam("id") int id, @PathParam("password") String pwd) {
        // ...
}
```

However it's another question whether this would be the right approach to authorize delete requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
@DELETE
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public void remove(@QueryParam(value = "id") int id, @QueryParam(value = "pw") String pw)     {
  .....
}
```

The resource must be request with question mark like url/url?id=1&pw=PASSWORD.
But is not very save to transmit the password over the url.